# Swing GUI, output does not show

Tags: java, swing

I have to build a GUI-based application to find the shortest path between two nodes.

The graph will be input by the user. The user will then draw the graph using nodes and edges. On mouseclicking a node will be created. On dragging the mouse from one node to another node, a weighted edge will be created. Then the user will input the start node and the  end node. Then the shortest path will be marked, but the output does not show.

What is the error?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class plus extends JFrame {
    int radius = 10, i = 0, x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2;
    double dis;
    int[] a = new int[100];
    int[] b = new int[100];

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JButton B1 = new JButton("Enter Nodes");
    JButton B2 = new JButton("Draw Edges");
    JButton B3 = new JButton("Start Node");
    JButton B4 = new JButton("End Node");
    JButton B5 = new JButton("Run");
    JButton B6 = new JButton("Clear");
    JButton button[] = new JButton[100];
    JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1 = new JInternalFrame();

    public plus() {
        setTitle("Shortest Path Finding");
        setSize(700, 600);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(jInternalFrame1, "Center");
        contentPane.add(panel2, "South");
        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);
        jInternalFrame1.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel2.add(B1);
        panel2.add(B2);
        panel2.add(B3);
        panel2.add(B4);
        panel2.add(B5);
        panel2.add(B6);
        B1.addActionListener(new B1Listener());
        B2.addActionListener(new B2Listener());
        /*B3.addActionListener(new B3Listener());
        B4.addActionListener(new B4Listener());
        B5.addActionListener(new B5Listener());*/
        B6.addActionListener(new B6Listener());
    }

    class drawedge {
        public void de() {
            jInternalFrame1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent event) {
                    jInternalFrame1MousePressed(event);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent event) {
                    jInternalFrame1MouseReleased(event);
                }
            });
        }

        public void jInternalFrame1MousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            for (int l = 0; l < i; l++) {
                if (e.getX() == a[l] && e.getY() == b[l]) {
                    x1 = a[l];
                    y1 = b[l];
                    break;
                }
            }
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();
        }

        public void jInternalFrame1MouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            for (int m = 0; m < i; m++) {
                if (e.getX() == a[m] && e.getY() == b[m]) {
                    x2 = a[m];
                    y2 = b[m];
                    x2 = e.getX();
                    y2 = e.getY();
                    Graphics g = getGraphics();
                    g.drawLine(x1 - 10, y1 + 20, x2 - 10, y2 + 20);
                    dis = ((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) - (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)) / 10;
                    if (dis < 0) {
                        dis = dis * -1;
                    }
                    dis = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(dis));
                    g.drawString("" + dis, (x2 + x1) / 2, (y2 + y1) / 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class drawnode {
        drawnode() {
            jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);
            jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        }

        public void dn() {
            jInternalFrame1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    jInternalFrame1MouseClicked(evt);
                }
            });
        }

        private void jInternalFrame1MouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            button[i] = new JButton();
            button[i].setBounds(x - 7, y - 30, 50, 30);
            jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().add(button[i]);
            button[i].setText(Integer.toString(i + 1));
            i++;
            a[i] = x - 7;
            b[i] = y - 30;
        }

    }

    class B1Listener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            drawnode d1 = new drawnode();
            d1.dn();

        }
    }

    class B2Listener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            drawedge d = new drawedge();
            d.de();
        }
    }

    /*class B3Listener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    }*/
    class B6Listener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().removeAll();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new plus();
        frame.setLocation(150, 50);
        frame.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: _out put didn't show what is the error_ have you tried to debug?

Comment: Did you run the program? What is the error? Any stacktrace?

Comment: What do you mean with "ouput"? Do the nodes not show in the Frame? The Edges? Or the marking of the path?

Comment: _out put didn't show what is the error_, can you elaborate please? What was supposed to be shown? Where is the logic that shows what was supposed to be shown? Sorry to bother, but your method names and variables do not give any hints...

Comment: I'm tried but didn't show error only GUI is runed

Comment: To half-quote the cheese shop sketch: Did anything happen at all?

Comment: Didn't show error but the result is not

Comment: when Iam run the program it java display only GUI but I press the button (for example: when i press the button run which created the result didn't show) i don't know anyone understand me

Comment: `getGraphics()`: you should never use that method.  You should have a `Node` class which stores a location, one or several incoming edge (of type `Edge`) and one or several outgoing edges (of type `Edge`). You should create an `Edge` class which has a start node (of type `Node`) and an end node (also of type `Node`). Finally, you create a component (which extends `JPanel` for example), you override `paintComponent()` and there you draw all the nodes and edges.

Comment: *i don't know anyone understand me* -> me neither... Can you show us a screenshot of what you **see** and try to explain what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Having tried the code I'm going to assume that the problem is with drawing edges.

Try the following
1. Click Enter Nodes and add some nodes
2. Click Draw Edges and try to draw some edges - nothing appers to happen so I'll assume that this is the root of your problem.
3. Try clicking anywhere on your frame other than a node.  You will see that you are still adding nodes!

You have two problems at this point
1. You add a mouse listiner in drawnode#dn and never remove it so you will continue to add nodes.
2. If you are trying to add an edges you are clicking a node (jbutton) and not a the frame so the mouse events you added in drawedge#de are never called.

Comment: Iam tried but when press the run button its not running

Comment: I ran ok for me after I added the imports that Guillaume Polet has now added to you code, why not try with his ammendements

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just tried your code and got the following on my screen:

[image]

As far as I can see, the GUI shows up and you can enter nodes. But when I try to add edges, it still is in the "add node" mode. So your problem is not really the run button, but before that the mode changing. Try to create a variable that holds your current mode. I would suggest an `enum`:

```
enum eMode {ADD_NODES, ADD_EDGES, SELECT_START_NODE, SELECT_END_NODE, READY}

eMode mode = ADD_NODES;
```

You can change this mode when you press one of the buttons in the bottom. When you click within the internal frame or on one of the node buttons, you first check what mode you are in. Depending on the mode, you then either add a new node at the clicked position, draw an edge (you might have to wait for the user to click on a second button for this), select the start or end node. Once you have selected both start and end node, the mode switches to `eMode.READY`. In this mode, pressing on the run button will start the shortest path algorithm and display the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is, apart from some style issues, and that I did not check if what you do is actually logical, simply that neither B3, B4 nor B5 (which is the run Button), has an `ActionListener`. No ActionListener, no action, no work, no output. Or am I missing something?